# Video name by video ID

Tags: youtube-api, google-bigquery, data-transfer, looker-studio, youtube-analytics-api

I am using the BigQuery Data Transfer Service to get data from YouTube Analytics to BigQuery and from there to Google Data Studio. This works fine, but the tables do not contain the video names. There are just the video IDs.

Best case was if I could get a field 'video_name' in here:
[image]

Is there a way to display the video names in Data Studio, e.g. for monitoring "Top Videos By Channel" in a chart?

Comment: It looks like this issue could be more related to the YouTube Reporting API side, so I added those tags in order to gain some visibility from the YouTube engineers, who [monitor questions under the `youtube-api` tag](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support). As I see it, the issue is that the the Reporting API does not expose any *video_title* / *video_name* dimension, as explained in the [Dimensions documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/dimensions), but hopefully a more specialized user can shed some light on this.

Comment: Hitting the same issue. You can lookup title using the Youtube API, but that's no help here. Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the youtube's data api, that can serve the purpose of yours,
I tried with this using `https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=` simply you need to provide single or mutiple video_ids like this `id=xriwC_UpJER,1BB_dyvjrpf` or just single id `id=1BB_dyvjrpf`.

Keep in mind that you need to be authorized to access this api, i-e you will need access token.